# C# NuGets Installation

Tags: c#, nuget, installshield

So I have a C# application that I am developing in Visual Studio. I am using a NuGet which was really easy to install. Newtonsoft JSON. I just had a quick question because I am new to windows development.

I know to use somethings in your project you need to add the dll or lib to your installer as well, in order for the project to use that library. Is this the same case for a NuGet? Do I need to add Newtonsoft JSON to my installer?

Im using Visual Studio 2015 if that matters.

Comment: Your installer will need to ensure that the assembly is included.  But there are many installers out there.  What are you using?

Comment: Installsheild. So I will need to make some configurations to Installsheild to add that nuget? or the dll/lib it produces

Comment: I googled some tutorials for adding a dll to my project, with little luck. All the tutorials that I found are all very old. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to just comment but can't yet.

In general, adding a package to a project through Nuget takes care of all the necessary referencing.

Also, if you look in your reference list in the project, and right-click on the assembly in question (in this case Newtonsoft.JSON), and go to its Properties, you will see an option "Copy Local".

If this is set to true, as the description says, "the reference will be copied to the output directory".

So, wherever your .exe/.dll/lib is output, there should also be a copy of Newtonsoft.JSON in there as well.

Edit:

As your question is quite confusing, the best I can say is that if you add a package through Nuget, it will NOT be *built into* your application, it will still be a separate DLL file that DOES need to be included in your installers list of included files.

Comment: Right, but the OP is talking about the *installer* -- not just compiling the app.

Comment: Which seems generally irrelevant. If he's not putting whatever the output of the project is in the installer, then what is he putting in there? Assuming the installer is using the output of the project as its file list, then having this property to true will ensure a copy of the DLL in question is in that directory.

Comment: The question is *all* about the installer.  Presumably the OP can run his app. Therefore the assembly is presumably where it needs to be when running the app locally.  Installers are an *entirely* different story and is the crux of the OP's question.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer a bit as I'm not entirely clear what he's asking. In any case, the DLL in question will need to included in any installers list of files, but if he is pointing directly to his project's output directory, with this property set to true, he will not have to worry about doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install nuget package to you installshield project.
You need need to include reference in you install project to your dependency.

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on the installer you use. Some will let you select the folder and will detect it automaticly, some don't.